# Adding significance brackets to ggplot geom_bar object in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, significance

I would like to add significance brackets to `ggplot` `geom_bar` object in r.

When I do searches for how to do this, it either shows just adding the astericks without the brackets, or it does so using a `geom_boxplot`.

I want the final product to look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reproducible example using `ggsignif`, with the built-in `iris` data set:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", fill = "#0079b9", geom = "col", width = 0.7) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("setosa", "versicolor"),
                                 c("versicolor", "virginica"),
                                 c("virginica", "setosa")),
              y_position = c(7, 7.5, 8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 8.9)) +
  ylab("Mean Sepal Length") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geom_bracket` and this allows you to manually type what you want for the bracket texts:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

summary = iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(
    mean_sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length)
  )

summary %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = mean_sepal_length)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_bracket(
    xmin = c("setosa", "versicolor", "setosa"),
    xmax = c("versicolor", "virginica", "virginica"),
    label = c("n.s.", "**", "p < 0.0075"),
    y.position = c(7, 8, 9)
  )
```

[image]
More info can be found here: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/geom_bracket.html